# Json total result mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am having difficulty displaying the total number of the result of the mysql query using json.

I tried this rule but it only returns like this:

```
{"Total1": "10"}
```

I need to return it with the []:

```
[{"Total1": "10"}]
```

Follows the php code:

```
<?php
include 'DatabaseConfig.php';
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT revenda, quantidade FROM app_venda";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$total1 = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row[total1] = $total1;
    $json = json_encode($row);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `json_encode( array(array('Total1' => $total1)) );`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you so much, it worked!

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_* functions. They are discouraged since amlost a decade, deprecated since PHP5.5 and removed since PHP7. Any piece of code that relies on them can be considered unsafe without a doubt for pratical use. For the sake of the program you are writing, the users that will use it and your own work as a programmer, you should switch to PDO as soon as possible. You shouldn't either even *write* code that contains these functions, even (especially) if it's in a website like this one instead of an IDE, since it propagates the behaviour to new coders.

Comment: Please use exit; after connection closed. In case in future if there is any HTML code or any other code beneath it then it may get executed.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to add another array around the data

```
$total1 = 10;
echo json_encode( array(array('Total1' => $total1)) );
```

Result

```
[{"Total1":10}]
```

Or using your code with a correction in the array definition. Notice `$row['total1'] = 10;` uses quotes around the array name to stop this error

> Notice: Use of undefined constant total1 - assumed 'total1'

```
$row['total1'] = 10;
echo json_encode( array( $row ) );
```

> Can I suggest in furutre you test code with these lines added to the top of all your scripts

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

> This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
>   generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Answer (score -1):

```
$total1 = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row[][total1] = $total1;
    $json = json_encode($row);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $json;
```

Comment: @Vaishnavesh - Please add some explanation of how and why this code addresses this OP's problem, preferably with links to relevant documentation, and relevant quotes supporting your explanation. Although the OP was clearly helped by this code, another user searching for a solution to a similar issue may find this question and answer, but not understand how this code may be useful.